# Eslint. Две конфигурации в одном проекте

Tags: eslint

Планируется разработка приложения на node.js. На фронте будет react.
Разработка будет идти с помощью vscode. Есть ли возможность настроить eslint для бекенда и для фронтенда отдельно. (фронтенд находится в папке client там свой package.json)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы правила ищутся рядом с `package.json`, значит да.

Помимо этого в справке написано, что можно правила вообще в самом `package.jsonё писать.